# How to implement the following as in the image using asp.net c# GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I need to implement the following in the asp.net Gridview. I have the excel sheet as in the image. Based on this image i need to implement data entry application using asp.net gridview.

[image: excel sheet]

As you can see in the image from S.NO. 1 TO 5 for every ID Description there are multiple Authors e.g 2,3 or 5. How to implement the same functionality using asp.net gridview so that for every ID Description, user can enter multiple authors while entering the record in the DB design and how to show the records back to gridview as in the excel sheet??

Kindly suggest regarding DB and gridview implementation to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: In the grid view you can not make this. You can make a custom control that is the one line render, and place this in a repeater sending to the custom control its data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are looking for `Nested GridView Control to Display Related Data`.See a link.
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992038%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link but that is for displaying the data from DB. But how to let the user to enter multiple Authors for the same ID Description during insert operation on Gridview?